# S3 signed urls change everytime on load even though keys are the same;no caching

Tags: reactjs, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, pre-signed-url

I have encountered a problem where I need to cache image urls in browser after first load so that on every refresh same files are not fetched again and instead they are obtained from browser cache. The blocker here is that s3 signed url contains 'date' and 'signature' parameters which change on every request and hence I cannot cache it. Is there some workaround to this?
Sample urls :

```
https://bucket.region-name.amazonaws.com/67/13/14/design1.png_1547473003445/V0/thumbnail/design1.png?X-Amz-Algorithm=AWS4-HMAC-SHA256&X-Amz-Credential=ASIATY536SGM6CWFJ%2F20190116%2Fap-south-1%2Fs3%2Faws4_request&X-Amz-Date=20190116T093449Z&X-Amz-Expires=900&X-Amz-Security-Token=FQoGZXIvYXdz%2F%2F%2F%2F%2F%2F%2F%2F%2FwEaDOQ2d%2FbrCADhrzi5LSKsAVrViSpTmyeTwlv8mgStqYJquyL2u4i3zqSOAFRE8fbHy7EbxH5yAmmWM94clRMm9to9LJDaxP96tAM4Za%2BFSzfr3fBTpHy%2Fq8N8fMT4%2FLv3Q5oX1k%2Fj9meYHpcH539LOLu8LmRuXGrPlbuHb7l4z7ZAWFB5MvootGvp0pfcEh6BqXr9R0iygJq3LWwoBhr5A9dRqSsLfWx9KTRTFi9KBkI%2FYtZCjEejdaVsExooufX74QU%3D&X-Amz-Signature=314c2ab2be7db4a90a3b20a79e2b53e8b915ca612ad3c6794136a4dac0fe6119&X-Amz-SignedHeaders=host
```

refereshed one :

```
https://bucket.region-name.amazonaws.com/67/13/14/design1.png_1547473003445/V0/thumbnail/design1.png?X-Amz-Algorithm=AWS4-HMAC-SHA256&X-Amz-Credential=ASIA536UOMZINFU%2F20190116%2Fap-south-1%2Fs3%2Faws4_request&X-Amz-Date=20190116T093659Z&X-Amz-Expires=900&X-Amz-Security-Token=FQoGZXIvYXdz%2F%2F%2F%2F%2F%2F%2F%2F%2FwEaDF4rMeLkeIEnbQWu6CKsAWTaVEcUia6oXeuaDObUF5Cirhzko1le9KGQfPKs5ZIwWk6o0qzHIzCe9uYdfBSmanXrfDxRHK33zbccphSwQkPI8mp%2Fl%2FGljXZALFDKZdRny4DnF2MXfy5WiFKBVSYHZ5onNZxSA4VrgNHeYbe6drI6QwMR9cHij13D8RK2XYDlmM6oVaCjGdMgL4QdpdHangaV0ZEq2GfOAYFfIps9nCM0WCH3Z3%2BpJFVfF9kouvb74QU%3D&X-Amz-Signature=5c5dead27c779299f5aef84e60e7c88a13f4cada9baa77e74e62b51caa1c0099&X-Amz-SignedHeaders=host
```

Answer (score 0):

The presigned URLs are used to give temporal permissons to a URL in a private bucket, you could opt for a public bucket or and an Authentication endpoint to the API.

Comment: Thankyou for the response. Could you please elaborate on the Authentication endpoint part of it.